# What do the individual parts of the full name mean when something like ResNet-FasterRCNN is mentioned?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow

What i mean by the title is as follows:

Say I went into [Tensorflows Object Detection Model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md) and picked some model like, Faster R-CNN ResNet101 V1 1024x1024.

My question is, what is the architecture and what is the technique? Does Faster-RCNN point to the **technique** the architecture (**i.e. ResNet 101**) uses or is FasterRCNN also a standalone architecture?

If what i'm saying above doesn't make much sense then what do both "Faster RCNN" & "ResNet 101" refer to within the context of the whole name of the model "Faster R-CNN ResNet101 V1 1024x1024"?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, object detection networks can be broken down into two parts: a backbone network which takes an input image and outputs a feature map, and the "head(s)", which produces the final detections from the feature map.

Backbones can often be swapped out for one another, and they're not usually the focus of research -- there's just much more interesting things to be explored in the heads. So in this context, "Faster R-CNN" refers to the design of the heads, and "ResNet 101" is the name of the backbone network.

Comment: So in the case of "RCNN", since the selective search process happens before features are extracted, would you still refer to it as the head of the operations? (or tail maybe would be more appropriate?)